# Basic property proof using ring axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Using the basic axioms of ring, how can we say that:

$x+z-y-z=x+z-(y+z)$? My first guess was to separate out $-1$ and then apply the distributive property. However, I am not sure I am allowed to assume $-1$ exists.

Note: this is part of a larger proof involving ordered rings.

Comment: You are allowed to assume -1 exists as the additive inverse of 1 (if you consider rings with 1).

Comment: Ok. What if we do not necessarily know that R is a ring with 1?

Comment: Then you take y+z as the (unique) additive inverse of -y -z (=-y+(-z)) and vice versa. Hence you can do the stuff above.

Comment: I think if one is trying to prove things using the basic axioms of a ring one needs to have brackets (since associativity is one of those basic axioms). i.e. you should have written something like $(x+z) + ((-y)+(-z)) = (x+z) + (-(y+z))$

Answer (score 1):

$$y+z+(-y)+(-z)=(y+(-y))+(z+(-z))=0$$ 
Thus 
$$y+z+(-y-z)=0$$ 
Thus
$$-y-z=-(y+z)$$